# Using parameters in QString insert function

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspberry-pi, qt5

I'm trying to create a project in QT in which I want to edit a speicific line in a text file, using the parameters given in my function. The current function has no paramaters, but my goal is for a function that looks something like this:

```
setSettings(int x, QString y)
{
    QString command="ssh root@192.168.0.110 ";
    command.insert(command.length(), QString("'sed -i '2s/.*/OFF/' car.txt'"));
}
```

This works as I want it to, but I want to use the parameters x and y to replace "2" and "OFF" in the case of the above example. How do I use those inside the quotation marks?

Comment: Use [QString::arg](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) to format your string?

Comment: And use `append()` instead of `insert()`.

Comment: @ypnos Can you explain the difference between the two? Why use append() instead of insert()?

Comment: The difference is that your code is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`arg`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg), in your case:

```
QString command="ssh root@192.168.0.110 ";
command.append(QString("'sed -i '%1s/.*/%2/' car.txt'").arg(x).arg(y));
```